# How to avoid duplicated service in Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working with Angular 7 and the Spotify WEB API and have made a service to keep all play and monitoring playback state logic in one place.

To keep it very simple, I'll take some logic out.

The service gets called with this:

```
  play() {
    this._service.playTracks(this.tracks);
    console.log('Playing mock track list');
    this.monitorPlayback();
  }
```

which plays an array of songs and then initiates monitoring.

```
  monitorPlayback () {
    interval(15000).subscribe(() => {
      monitoring logic here;
    });
```

This function GET's the current playback state of the user to do some stuff with it - which is of no importance to this question.

Now here is my problem. If I queue songs multiple times - the whole thing (obviously) gets triggered twice. So I'm not polling once in 15 seconds but twice. How do I kill an already initiated instance of monitorPlayback()? I do not want to add more logic to play currently (that might change, however).

Comment: Implement state: `let isRunning = false;`, turn it to true on monitorPlayback and don't monitor if it's already true

Comment: on top of what Dan said you can use `takeUntil` and `repeatWhen` operator to unsubscribe any previous subscription and resume a new subscription each time you call `play()` . just set `isRunning = false` in your play() method and use it as the predicate in the rxjs operators I mentioned above. Or you can create two boolean properties to handle the toggling .

Comment: That sounds like a proper solution. I'll take my time implementing this. I've currently gone with Dan's solution that I'm just not starting monitoring twice. Thanks for the help.

Now I'm really desperate to look for some testers but thats another story xD